# How to use REST API's

Tags: rest, api-design

I know some basic programming languages but im new at using API's.

Can someone please explain how, or where do i run my API's codes?

Will the API's be run on the website i'm trying to get my data from or can it be run on a client or from another different running environment or platform?

Comment: REST APIs can run on any HTTP server and can be called from any HTTP client, though a browser-side client will have more restrictions for the sake of security (look up CORS for one example). This question is probably too broad for the parameters of how Stack Overflow works, so I'd recommend doing some research and coming back with more specific answerable questions.

Comment: There's a lot of easily available information on the interwebs on this topic that's very helpful and more abundant than a brief answer someone might provide here. Have you tried a Google search on "how to use a rest api" for example? Run into anything there you're not sure about? A REST API call is an HTTP request to a server with what looks like a path you might type into your browser to access a website. For calls that get data, the server returns information, often in JSON format (which your REST API client would need to receive and interpret).

Answer (score 1):

Apis should only (I say "should" because I am not sure that something like this can be done on the client side) to run on the server.

when you get information from an api you are not executing it on the client. you are only getting the data you requested for the endpoints you used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you plan to use REST APIs as a consumer or producer?  That is, do you want to expose your data, systems and processes as resources for an end consumer, or do you want to be the consumer creating applications that leverage services?

---

## The Producer

To produce REST APIs, you'll need to run your API providers using a web server.  Just about any web server will do, so long as it can map resource paths to functions.  Some common ones are:

- Node.JS with [Express.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4)
- Nginx with [Python/Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/deploying/uwsgi/)
- Java using [Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)

You should be able to run whatever you chose on nearly any hosting provider, cloud VM or wherever else you usually run websites.

---

## The Consumer

You can use Rest APIs anywhere you have network connectivity.  You'll find this commonly in mobile applications, web applications, IoT devices, etc where data are combined from multiple providers on to a single application for end users.  The key feature as a consumer you'll be looking for is a directory of API providers from which you can build your application.

[ProgrammableWeb](https://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory) maintains one such list.